# Check if any unselected DropDownList

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say there's 3 dropdownlist, how do I check if there's any unselected dropdownlist?

```
var unselected = $('.dropdown:selected').lenght;

if(unselected > 0){
alert('At least one dd is not selected')
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the html to your dropdowns? Or are all three have the the same `class="dropdown"`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you'd like check whether some of the dropdown lists have not been picked one available option except the disabled one.

You can do like below:

```js
function checkSelected(){
  $('select').each(function(){
    console.log($('option',this).not(':disabled').is(':selected') ? 'selected' : 'no selection for ' + $(this).attr('id') )
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option disabled selected value> -- Please select -- </option>
  <option value="1">A Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">A Test 2</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
  <option disabled selected value> -- Please select -- </option>
  <option value="1">B Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">B Test 2</option>
</select>
<select id="select3">
  <option disabled selected value> -- Please select -- </option>
  <option value="1">C Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">C Test 2</option>
</select>

<button onclick="checkSelected()">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified code from @Sphinx. Displays the count of the "unselected" drop downs and the "total" drop downs.

```js
function checkSelected(){
      var i = 0;
      var total =  $('.dropdown').length;  
      $('.dropdown').each(function(){
            //console.log($(this).attr('id'));  
            if(!$('option',this).not(':disabled').is(':selected')) i++;
            // console.log(i + " dropdowns are NOT selected"); 
      });
      console.log(i + " of " + total +" dropdowns are NOT selected");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="select1" class="dropdown">
      <option disabled selected value> -- Please select -- </option>
      <option value="1">A Test 1</option>
      <option value="2">A Test 2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="select2" class="dropdown">
      <option disabled selected value> -- Please select -- </option>
      <option value="1">B Test 1</option>
      <option value="2">B Test 2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="select3" class="dropdown">
      <option disabled selected value> -- Please select -- </option>
      <option value="1">C Test 1</option>
      <option value="2">C Test 2</option>
    </select>

    <button onclick="checkSelected()">Click me!</button>
```